# Conceptual: solving maze with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, maze

There are many many maze solving algorithm out there. But just now I came across a description of a quantum computer that states

> A quantum computer can  try all the paths of a binary maze at one
>   time,  and dramatically reduce the time needed to  solve a childish
>   problem like a maze

But couldn't we do that right now. I'm no expert in parallel computing but (assuming I can make as many many thread I want) couldn't we just create a new thread every time our program sees a forked path in the maze. This would try out both paths at the same time (right?).

It would be like trial-and-error except we try all the solutions at (almost) the same time.

Prerequisite: very very large number of core at disposal.

Comment: With an **infinite** number of cores it's accurate, but that's a strong prerequisite. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New threads are not all actually executed in parallel - you can only execute as many threads in parallel as you have cores *(so, on a 4-core computer, only 4 cores can be running code at one time)*.  The OS thread-scheduler switches which thread is running on which core many times a second, so it *looks* like they are running at the same time, but really they are not.

If you had enough cores to assign one core to every possible path, then yes, your idea would work.  This would actually be possible for smaller mazes on a GPU, which these days can have upwards of 5k+ cores.

Comment: I don't think a GPU would work for this type of problem, because each thread actually operates in sync (each thread is processing the same instruction at the same time) and the branch divergence penalty would be huge.

Comment: @GuyGreer: That's only true per SM.  IIRC, on current-generation Nvidia cards there are 32 threads per SM, with only half of those running in lock-step *(with some funny name, like "half-warp," or something)*.  So, even assuming we couldn't write it so the half-warps are mostly in sync *(which we should be able to)*, the maximum penalty for thread-divergence is 16x, which, even in that extreme case is still a large speed up, given 5k+ cores in the new Nvidia Tesla cards.

Comment: GPUs have come a long way from not being able to handle branches at all, :).

Comment: @GuyGreer: Actually it's been this way for as long as GPGPU programming has been a thing.  Though IIRC *(again)*, in the early days it was 32-threads (a full warp) running in lock-step, rather than 16-threads (half-warp)